# Find the area ratio of the triangular regions $ATK$ and $LKS$ .

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: If, $T$ and $K$ are points of tangency, measure of the $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AB}$ is twice the measure of the $\angle ASL$, $BS=3$, $KS=1$ and $\frac{TB}{4} =\frac{AT}{3}$ .Calculate the area ratio of the triangular regions $ATK$ and $LKS$ . (Answer: $\frac{9}{4}$)

[image]

$ \frac{S_{\triangle KLS}}{S_{\triangle AKT}} = \frac{KL.KS}{AK.KT}\\
\therefore \frac{S_{\triangle KLS}}{ S_{\triangle AKT}}=\frac{KL}{AK.KT}\\
BK.AK = LK.KT\implies 4AK = KL.KT\\ \therefore 
\frac{S_{\triangle KLS}}{ S_{\triangle AKT}}=\frac{4KL}{KL.KT.KT}=\frac{4}{KT^2}$

....???

Comment: Please introduce the points one by one instead of starting with "If $T$ and $K$ are points of tangency..." and adding some picture at some later point. Because if they are not, nothing is given. This is your responsability to present the problem in a clean shape, even if the source did it in a fuzzy mode. Then please ask a clear question, then showing the own effort to answer this one question. Using something like "... ???" is really a bad mode to present a question.

Comment: @dan_fulea  I understand your statements but I will do mine:
1) "Then please ask a clear question" ..for me the title is very clear for what the question is about
2) "???"..it's just to indicate that from that point on I couldn't develop the issue further...just so the resolution doesn't get "lost in the air". I don't see any problem..but if it's mandatory I don't put it anymore..

Comment: @dan_fulea 3) "Please introduce the points one by one instead ... This is your responsibility to present the problem in a clean shape". Those who follow my questions already know that I reproduce the question faithfully, precisely so that there are no questions about the lack of data ..etc In my opinion, the question must be solved according to the original question, because if it was prepared, the person who created it created an answer based on the original text. I can't change a question because that way I could be modifying the statement somehow leading to a wrong solution.

Comment: @peta arantes, the correct answer is $\frac{1}{4}$ or $\frac{4}{1}$, depending on how you arrange. But you have given the correct answer as $\frac{9}{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Claim 1** : $KT$ is the angle bisector of $\angle ATB$

Construction:

1. Draw $DT$ tangent to the circles at point $T$
2. Let $AT$ intersect smaller circle at $C$. Draw $CK$.

Proof:
Using Alternate-segment theorem we get :

$$\angle CKA = \angle CTK..........(1)$$
$$\angle DTC = \angle CKT = \angle ABT..........(2)$$

Now, In $\triangle ATB$

$$\angle AKT = \angle KTB  + \angle KBT ......(3)$$

From equations $(2)$ and $(3)$

We get, $$\angle CKA = \angle KTB....(4)$$

From equations $(1)$ and $(4)$, we get our result.

In $\triangle ATB$ , if we apply Angle-bisector theorem

we get,

$$\frac{TB}{AT} = \frac{BK}{AK}$$

Therefore, AK = 3$

Now, By the secant property of circles

We get, $LK.KT = 12$

Now, its trivial to prove that

$BS = LS = LK = 3$ and $KT$ = $4$ {$\angle AKS = \angle ATB = \frac{1}{2} \angle AOB$}

Therefore, $$\frac{[LKS]}{[ATK]} = \frac{1}{4}$$